Models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$
I have three questions about this topic:

How do you denote a generic model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? For example, a model of $\mathsf{PA}$ is usually denoted as a triple $(\mathbb N, 0, S)$. The first thing I thought of is a pair $(M, \in)$. I initially considered this potentially problematic since $M$ would possibly be the set of all sets, which is proven not to exist. However, at the same time, Russell's paradox only holds under the assumption of the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms, which only the members of $M$ are required to satisfy, not $M$ itself.

Since $M$ is not a set in the usual sense (that is, an object satisfying the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$), what kind of object is it? Furthermore, how are ordered pairs defined outside of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? Would we need a stronger version of set theory to define these concepts, such as some kind of "ambient theory"?

If the answer to my last question is affirmative, I could ask question 2 again for this new set theory (since a model would still require a "set" of all the sets of this theory). This process could potentially go on forever. Is this not problematic?



$M$ is a set in ZFC, but it is not a set in the model. Those are different things. Essentially, the inner set theory is not the same as the outer set theory.

In particular, $\in$ in the logic is not certain to map to $\in$ in the outer ZFC.

@ThomasAndrews Sorry, I don't understand either of your comments at all.

"A poset is a set $P$ and a relation $\le_P$ on $P$ satisfying the transitivity, reflexivity and antisymmetry axioms". "A zificoset is a set $M$ an a relation $\in_M$ on $M$ satisfying the extensionality, regularity, pairing, (and so forth for all ZFC axioms) axioms." There is nothing magically different about these two definitions... they are completely analogous and have the exact same status. Only, a "zificoset" is a name I made up for what is normally called a "model of ZFC". (Or we could go the other way an call a poset a "model of the poset axioms".)

@spaceisdarkgreen okay, I think I get it. Just a couple of questions, if we speak of sets outside of ZFC, what information do we have about them? Also, since Russel's paradox follows from the axiom of specification, does this mean a set can contain all sets, if it's not a model of ZFC?

@Elvis I don't know what you mean by "speak of sets outside of ZFC". If our set theoretical universe satisfies ZFC (or anything remotely like it), no set can contain all sets, regardless of what properties that set might have.

@Elvis Again, we're not doing anything weird here. We are still working in ZFC, and the model is a set. It might even be countable, and this statement has the same status as "there are countable partial orders". It definitely doesn't contain every set, and there's no reason to think it would. The fact that the theory it's a model of is the same as the theory we're working in has no impact on any of this.

Actually, a model of ZFC is a set, just like any other set.
Specifically model of ZFC is a set $M$ together with a binary relation $\in_M$ on $M$, i.e. $\in_M \subseteq M \times M$.


... I initially considered this potentially problematic since $M$ would possibly be the set of all sets


$M$ cannot be the (class) of all sets, because $M$ is a set, not a class.
You are probably mixing up sets in the model, vs. sets in the metatheory here. The model $M$ contains some sets in a constructed universe, with a constructed $\in_M$ relation. They don't necessarily map directly to sets in the meta-theory because they have a different $\in_M$ relation, as @Thomas Andrews points out in the comments.
A "toy example" would be, imagine all the sets that exist are just $0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 10$. Then $M$ might be some subset of these, like $\{2, 3, 5\}$ together with some relation like $2 \in_M 5, 5 \in_M 3$. It has nothing to do with the relation on the sets in our meta theory.


Since $M$ is not a set in the usual sense ...


$M$ is a set in the usual sense, so the rest of this question does not apply.


If the answer to my last question is affirmative


Again this does not apply as 2 was based on a false premise. :)

I hope that clarifies!
Note that, assuming ZFC is consistent, we know that models of ZFC do exist, by Gödel's completeness theorem.
So, it is possible to construct $M$ and $\in_M$ that satisfy the axioms of ZFC.
But the reason this is not paradoxical is that $\in_M$ may be a rather pathological relation;
it does not necessarily correspond to the usual is-an-element-of relation on our usual sets.

Sorry, I don't understand. The standard model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ contains all sets. These objects should be contained in $M$, just like all natural numbers are contained in $\Bbb N$ in a generic model of $\mathsf{PA}$. So how can $M$ be a set? Shouldn't you define models of a theory "outside" of such theory?

@Elvis The "standard model of ZFC" is not a model of ZFC, I don't know what objects you're talking about, because it's a set by definition, and no.

@Elvis (There is a more delicate notion of a proper-class model, but when someone says "model of ZFC", or "model of anything" they usually mean the domain is a set.)

Any model of ZFC contains a copy of $V_\omega$, but that's about as far as you can get. It doesn't contain these objects because $V_\omega$ is the standard model of ZFC, whatever that means (ZFC doesn't really have a "standard model"), it contains them because they can be encoded in finite formulas and proven to exist with finitely many applications of empty set, pairing and union. There is no reason to expect that an arbitrary real number would exist in a model of ZFC and in fact if ZFC is consistent it has countable models, which do not contain all of the real numbers.

@Elvis To summarize what was said above -- the theory of models of ZFC is rather different than the theory of models of PA; unfortunately we don't have a nice decomposition into "standard" and "nonstandard" models the way you are thinking. You might want to consult your model theory textbook; I recommend Pete Clark's notes. I assure you that a model is a set. Therefore, a model of ZFC cannot contain all sets due to Russell's paradox.

Just to add to pasta bee's example (and the following may make you rather unhappy!) :) the following is a theorem: if ZFC is consistent, then it has a model $M$ in which there exist elements $s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots$ such that $s_1 \ni_M s_2 \ni_M s_3 \ni_M \cdots$ is an infinite decreasing chain. Very uncomfortable as we know such decreasing chains are impossible by the axiom of foundation! Nevertheless, the result stands. The "resolution" of the paradox is that even though this chain exists, $M$ does not know about the chain, and cannot construct it. So $M$ still satisfies foundation.
